# How do I dual-boot Kali Linux With ISO (no CD/USB/DVD)

Tags: boot, usb, kali-linux

I am trying to install Kali Linux 1.0.7 to my Windows 8.1 32-bit PC. I have the ISO, but I have no CD's, USB Sticks, or DVD in my home so I was wondering how can I install Kali Linux without CD/USB/DVD? I've tried UNetBootIn but that didn't work. So what do I do?

Comment: How did unetbootin  not work ?

Comment: Network install? https://superuser.com/questions/42263/how-to-install-windows-7-from-the-network

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're trying to boot your PC from an ISO located on your hard drive.

I've never done this before and I don't know if it will work, but **[EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/wiki/easybcd)** can add an ISO image to the boot menu. You can then boot from it and install Linux. After that boot back into Windows and use EasyBCD to delete the ISO boot entry.

See https://neosmart.net/wiki/easybcd/portable-entries/iso-images/

Comment: I've tried EasyBCD and whenever I start the OS, it takes me to a terminal called Grub4Dos and I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to install it without modifying your grub, I would place the ISO somewhere in the drive. Boot my machine, when grub menu appears I would go to command line grub, and from there start the ISO. It is easier to boot from a UUID so that you don't have to identify the chain position of the drive/partition you want to boot from. To idendify your drive UUID you can check your fstab which will probably be set that way, or just execute `blkid` which will give you de ids of your devices.

```
search --fs-uuid YOUR_DRIVE_UUID --set=root
set iso=Path_and_name_to_the_iso
```

You should load the modules you need if your drive have an ext2 partition `insmod ext2` and so on...

```
set opt="findiso=$iso boot=live noconfig=sudo username=root hostname=kali"
linux (loop)/live/vmlinuz $opt
initrd (loop)/live/initrd.img
```

Finally just enter the command `boot` and your ISO will be loaded and you will be able to install Kali.

Becarefull when your installation is finished, since it will ask to modify your grub, you may want to modify it manually in your ubuntu installation or let the kali install set it in that partition (I'm talking about grub.cfg)

Edit: UUID is better if you use it in your grub.cfg, if you are going to type it (which is the case I'm talking about) it is better to identify the drive and set it root with (hd0,msdos1) as Ruslan Gerasimov stated in his post.

Answer (score 1):

[Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) can make your external drive bootable with certain ISOs without formatting the drive - it keeps all the data and adds the MBR to it, along with some unpacked folders and files from the ISO. But be careful, it has an option to *format the drive*, tick that checkbox before pressing *next*.

If you want to install Ubuntu in a normal way, to separate the partition, then you'll need to write your ISO to CD/DVD/USB and then boot from it (you'll have to tell the BIOS about it). If you have had any linux distribution previously installed, you could add a boot menu entry to the GRUB and tell it to run certain ISO image from a specific drive.

Do you want to install Ubuntu to the same Windows partition? Because with [WUBI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wubi) you can install Ubuntu to a Windows partition alongside with your current Windows, just by running all stuff from Windows. See the link I put on WUBI.

If you had had Linux already then to install ISO without having CD/DVD ot USB, you could run it as LIVE from you hard drive. The steps for this are as follows:

- Place your ISO file to `/live`:

`sudo mkdit /live`

`sudo cp somelinux.iso /live`

- Add new menu entry to the `grub.cfg`

`sudo gedit /etc/grub.d/40_custom`

```
menuentry 'ISO Ubuntu 14.04 2014 Live' --class os --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --group group_main {
                set isofile="/live/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso"

         insmod ext2
         insmod loopback
         insmod iso9660      
                loopback loop (hd0,msdos5)$isofile      

                linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz.efi  file=(loop)/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed noprompt boot=casper persistent iso-scan/filename=/$isofile quiet splash --
                initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz


}
```

TO DO:

1. change in the menu entry above the code name for your partition, holding `/live/somelinux.iso`, in my case it's `hd0,msdos5` because it is on `/dev/sda5`/
2. change the file name from somelinux.iso to yours, in my case I have: `ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso`

   - update GRUB

`sudo update-grub`

- reboot

Comment: I don't want to install Ubuntu. I want to install Kali Linux, and it's Debian 7 based. Plus, I want to install it to another partition without CD/USB/DVD. And I want to install it with Windows 8.1 Pro, and I don't have Linux already.

Comment: But ill try WUBI.

Comment: WUBI only works with Ubuntu, not different Linux OSes.

Comment: There are Kali tools which can be installed on Ubuntu

Comment: From my point of view having Kali (or Ubuntu + Kali Tools) installed on Windows partitions avoids a number of features from a variety of security principles of Unix and particularity Kali called to defend. But you know better what you do.

Comment: Whenever I install Kali Linux with Unetbootin, it takes me to a terminal that says Grub4DOS and I don't know how to use that.

Answer (score 0):

please open your iso with the help of winmount into new drive then you click kali linux setup after it will open the menu takes your permission for starting the kali linux installation. You can give permission to them

Answer (score 0):

The easiest, least-fuss way is to go buy a USB stick.  They're dirt-cheap. Even here in Australia you can get a 16GB USB stick for $5 ($1AUD ~= $0.70 USD).

Answer (score 0):

You can extract an ISO to one of your HDD partition (be sure to format as FAT32), for example `/dev/sda7`, then use `easyuefi` to set a uefi boot item for this partition.

When you boot from this partition, select graphic installation, it will ask you to install from a CD, then you can go to command-line mode by <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>. then type `mount /dev/sda7 /cdrom` to mount this partition as a CD.

After that <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> to go to the graphic mode and continue.

If there is still some errors,use key <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> to open the log output, and check the error.

For example the error is "`/dists/kali-rolling` not found", then you can make a dir names "`/dists/kali-rolling`",and `copy -r dists/kali-last-snapshot/* /dists/kali-rolling/`.

Switch to graphic mode and continue.  It seems everything will work!